# Compiling into executable file

Tags: c++, c, compilation, exe

I am currently writing a programming language in C/C++ as an exercise (but mostly for fun).  At the moment it compiles into a list of commands that are then executed (kind of like a low-level API).  Its working fantastically, however, I think it would be more exciting if instead of having a interpreter executable, having the language actually compile into a .exe file.  I don't know if it is possible or how challenging this might be.  I could not find any resources to help me with this.  - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider writing a [frontend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end) for LLVM ([tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/)) or GCC ([article from linux journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7884)) - if thats still fun for you is a different question.

Answer (score 2):

It would certainly be possible, although it could be a fair bit of work to produce all of the necessary parts to make a runnable binary. If that is what you are trying to learn about, then it could be a great exercise.

However, if you are simply looking to make it run faster, there are other options.  For example, you could possibly emit C/C++ code based on the input program and then compile/link that.

Comment: Writing a translator that converts the input program to C source is probably a good first step (by the way, that's how the first C++ implementation worked!).  Once you've solved that, writing a compiler frontend for your language should be a bit easier.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that a complete translator is a compiler. All gcc does is translate from C to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be clear about the syntax and lexical of your language code in a formal way.
Then, you could take a look on [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)). 
That builds a lexical analyzer, that you can use to generate the C code (or whatever) you need.

If your language doesn't use dynamic types, then you could get it easy.